# Filtering a list containing mixed date formats in Python

Tags: python, list, filter

Say I have a list of dates in python formatted as either `YYYY-mm-dd` or `YYYY-mm`.

```py
['2020-08-11', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-09', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-07',
 '2020-08-06', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-02',
 '2020-08-01', '2020-08', '2020-07', '2020-06', '2020-05', '2020-04',
 '2020-03', '2020-02', '2020-01']
```

I want to drop any `YYYY-mm` date from the list, if a more specific date already exists.

So in the example above, we would need to remove `'2020-08'` because `'2020-08-01'` to `'2020-08-11'` are in the list.

So the filtered list would be this:

```py
['2020-08-11', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-09', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-07',
 '2020-08-06', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-02',
 '2020-08-01', '2020-07', '2020-06', '2020-05', '2020-04', '2020-03',
 '2020-02', '2020-01']
```

Is there an elegant and quick way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you were to just turn all the dates into the same format of YYYY-MM-dd, and then took a unique, wouldn't that accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient way:

```
data = ['2020-08-11', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-09', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-07', '2020-08-06', 
        '2020-08-05', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-01', '2020-08', '2020-07', 
        '2020-06', '2020-05', '2020-04', '2020-03', '2020-02', '2020-01']

for i in data:
    try:
        # remove last 3 characters for example 
        # for data "2020-08-11" [:-3] would be "2020-08"
        data.remove(i[:-3])
    except:
        # Already has been removed
        pass
```

value of `data` would be:

```
['2020-08-11', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-09','2020-08-08', '2020-08-07','2020-08-06',
 '2020-08-05', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-01', '2020-07', 
 '2020-06', '2020-05', '2020-04', '2020-03', '2020-02', '2020-01']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a set of all the month parts from the full dates, then filter out entries from the original data that appear in that set:

```py
months_in_dates = {d[:7] for d in data if len(d) > 7}
filtered = [d for d in data if d not in months_in_dates]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, wouldn't the following give you the same result? Since you are working with DateTime, ideally you should work with DateTime types instead of string operations. So would this approach work? (convert all to datatype of same format and take unique)

```
a = ['2020-08-11', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-09', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-07', '2020-08-06','2020-08-05', 
     '2020-08-04', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-01', '2020-08', '2020-07', '2020-06', 
     '2020-05', '2020-04', '2020-03', '2020-02', '2020-01']

np.unique([pd.to_datetime(i, format='%Y-%m-%d') for i in a])
```

```
array([Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-04-01 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-05-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-07-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-08-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-03 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-08-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-05 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-08-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-08-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-09 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-08-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-11 00:00:00')],
      dtype=object)
```